# How can send push notifications to web application on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, web-push

I struggle to find a solution how can I send web push notification to iOS devices? For Android there is no problem I use service worker and GCM.

But I found service worker for iOS push notifications is under construction.Is there a way for iOS devices?

Answer (score 1):

If by web application you consider an app that opens in Safari the answer is: you can't send web notifications to iOS. Documentation:

> Notifications for websites do not appear on iOS

If your web application is a native app with web view in it for content loading then you'll have to use native push notifications.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way for iOS devices?

It's not possible at the moment and there isn't any workaround for websites.

You need to create a native or hybrid app for iOS if you want push notifications.

[Let’s ask Apple to add Web Push Notifications to iOS](http://blog.pushpad.xyz/2017/06/lets-ask-apple-to-add-web-push-notifications-to-ios/)